# PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

I'm trying to install a PHP script on my server but keep getting an error...

[08-Sep-2014 15:13:32 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in `/public_html/server/websocket.class.php` on line 30

[08-Sep-2014 15:13:32 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in `public_html/server/websocket.class.php` on line 30

Code on line 30:
`socket_select($changed, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, NULL);`

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you give us the line which calls this function?

Comment: while (true) 
        {
            $changed = $this->sockets;
            socket_select($changed, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, NULL);
            foreach ($changed as $socket) 
            {

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass variables:

```
$write = NULL;
$except = NULL; 

socket_select($changed, $write, $except, NULL);
```

as [socket_select()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) takes references as parameters

this is because expression `$write = NULL` passes result to function which is NULL not $write

Comment: I tried this and still had no luck... :/ Would you mind if I sent you the file and you had a look at it? Upload it to my Dropbox for you?

Comment: Here is a link to the file...

Server.php - https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8ose87vfqib5v4/server.php?dl=0

websocket.class - https://www.dropbox.com/s/lceirwu05suhh0d/websocket.class.php?dl=0

The websocket is the file that errors! :(

Comment: @ashbridge yes so use my answer? change `socket_select($changed, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, NULL);` to code from my answer....